# Android Firebase Create Notification Based On Recyclerview Condition

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to Create a Notification system as Recycerview Value change.I have written Below Code in my `onbind` method. It is creating notification but problem is creating notification everytime Though I need to create it based on condition `if(tBii>0 && notify>0)` How can I stop notification if condition is not met

```
 public void bind(final Book_Activebid book, String key){

        int tBii=Integer.parseInt(book.gettBii());
        int notify=Integer.parseInt(book.getNotify());

        if(tBii>0 && notify>0){

            String last_1=book.getLst_1();
            String last_2=book.getLst_2();
            String last_3=book.getLst_3();

            if(last_1!=null && last_1!=null && last_1!=null){
                notifyThis("Notification", last_1,last_2+" Has "+last_3);
            }
        }
  }
```

And this is my notifyThis method

```
public void notifyThis(String title,String subtext,String message) {

    NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this.mContext);
    b.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.flag_bulgaria)
            .setTicker("Notification")
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setSubText(subtext)
            .setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 })
            .setLights(Color.RED, 3000, 3000)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setContentInfo("Bii");

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(mContext,MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent conPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext,0,notificationIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    b.setContentIntent(conPendingIntent);

    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) this.mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nm.notify(1, b.build());

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why book varible is final ?

Final variable cant re-assign value so it will always show notify